# Country code gets appended in the field after jquery validation error in intl-tel Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, intl-tel-input

I'm using the following code to validate country code and contact number :

```
var e = window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#phone"), { separateDialCode: !0, preferredCountries: [currentCountry], hiddenInput: "full", utilsScript: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/utils.js" });
```

but the issue is when i validate

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
                "phoneNumValidation",
                function (el, t) {
                   return e.isValidNumber();
                },
                return  "Please Enter Valid Phone Number"
            ),
```

on error country code is appended existing number.

[image]

there are some other fields which are being validated so as soon jquery validator is fired extra country code is being appended.

Comment: jQuery Validate can not alter the content of a user input field.  Seems like the `utils.js` script is the problem... perhaps include more info about that in the question.

Comment: [As per the webpage for the International Telephone Input jQuery plugin](https://intl-tel-input.com):  *"The user types their national number and the plugin gives you the full standardized international number"* <- that sounds like your problem.